# HOW TO USE SHARED PREFERENCES IN FRAGMENT ACTIVITY

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm facing a problem while i use this code in a fragment , I did few changes by some of your help..But still have few errors..

this is the code i want to transfer in to a fragment activity from a normal Activity..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final static String SHARED_NAME_STRING="sharedp";
final static String USER_NAME_STRING="user";

Button button;
EditText editText;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameEditText);
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButton);

    Log.d("DICTIONARY", "main activity started");


    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(SHARED_NAME_STRING, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userNameString=sharedPreferences.getString(USER_NAME_STRING, "");

    editText.setText(userNameString);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String string=editText.getText().toString();
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, DictionaryListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("user", string);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(USER_NAME_STRING, string);
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And it showing error like MODE_PRIVATE cannot resolve to a variable.

So i changed into Context.MODE_PRIVATE,then it shows unreachable code on the line of "editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameEditText);"

HOW TO RECTIFY IT ?

THIS IS MY FRAGMENT NOW LOOKS LIKES :

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

final static String SHARED_NAME_STRING="sharedp";
final static String USER_NAME_STRING="user";

Button button;
EditText editText;
Context c;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


public FragmentA() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    editText=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.userNameEditText);
    button=(Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.enterButton);

    Log.d("DICTIONARY", "main activity started");

    Context c =getActivity();
    sharedPreferences=this.c.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_NAME_STRING,MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userNameString=sharedPreferences.getString(USER_NAME_STRING, "");

    editText.setText(userNameString);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String string=editText.getText().toString();
            Intent intent=new Intent("android.intent.action.JJJJ");
            intent.putExtra("user", string);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(USER_NAME_STRING, string);
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}



}
```

Comment: Welcome to this SO community. Please read up on SO link http://stackoverflow.com/tour. You can gain reputation points just by reading it briefly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply , replace

```
getSharedPreferences(SHARED_NAME_STRING,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: then it shows unreachable code on the line "editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameEditText);"

Comment: try SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have `return` in this code:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
```

Suggested code:

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
editText= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userNameEditText);
...
return view;
}
```

Notes:

- Notice the `return` keyword is removed. This caused your compile error of

> unreachable code on the line of....

- Instead of `getView()`, now you can use `view`.
- You are supposed to return a View type object. Hence the code `return view;` at the end of method `onCreateView`

Good luck and have fun...

Comment: @raMEesssahlus, Did it solve your problem? I hope u get a chance to read the SO tutorial briefly?